# Why didn't time loop reset Tree's hairstyle?

Tags: happy-death-day

In the movie *Happy Death Day 2U* (2019), Tree wakes up from her bed after getting shocked to death in the bathtub. She wakes up with this funny static hairstyle:

[image: Tree with a fuzzy hairstyle due to being shocked to her death]

Why didn't the time loop reset her hairstyle?

Comment: Because it's funny

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Valorum is correct that the main reason is [Rule of Funny](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny) (TV Tropes link warning). However, it could also be an indication of what Tree learned about her time loop in the previous movie, that she is suffering progressive damage from her deaths that will eventually kill her for good, so she can't afford to just waste them.

From [this review](https://www.pluggedin.com/movie-reviews/happy-death-day-2017/):

> And though it appears that each of Tree’s brutal deaths have no obvious effect on her once the next day begins, we find out that’s not exactly true. After a hospital visit and X-rays, she discovers that the bone fractures, stabbings and various physical impacts of past lives are having a toll on her current body—leaving her weakened and in danger of permanently dying.

From [the script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/happy-death-day-2017.pdf):

> Dr. Winter opens a file and puts up a series of X-RAYS on
>   the LIGHT BOARD.
>
> DR. WINTER.
>   We just got these back from the
>   lab. You see here --
>
> He runs his finger over a CHEST X-RAY.
>
> DR. WINTER (CONT’D).
>   These are your lungs. There’s some
>   scar tissue here. At first we
>   thought it was a sign of
>   pneumothorax.
>   (off Tree’s blank
>   stare).
>   A collapsed lung. But then we saw
>   these...
>
> He points to light-colored lines crisscrossing through
>   her NECK and LOWER ABDOMEN.
>
> DR. WINTER (CONT’D).
>   These are signs of major trauma,
>   Teresa. Given the severity of the
>   scar tissue and the size of the
>   lesions...
>   He shakes his head, unable to finish his sentence.
>
> TREE.
>   What?!
>   Slowly, Dr. Winter turns his baffled gaze on Tree.
>
> DR. WINTER.
>   You should be dead.

Answer (score 4):

In the original movie, we see that damage from previous iterations is carried over between lives- this happens when she goes to the doctor’s office and get the xrays/MRI’s and all of the scars and healed fractures from her previous deaths are evident. Life is almost, but not quite perfectly, reset. This is the cause of the countdown, the dramatic tension in the plot. In contrast to something like Groundhog Day where the repeat can appear to continue as infinitum, Happy Death Day makes it clear that your body can only take dying and miraculously healing for so long.

In short- if bone breaks (from death trauma) can carry over, why not frizzled hair (also from death trauma)?

Comment: Can you give some examples of injuries carrying over?

Comment: @Valorum updated to explain that she actually went to a doctors office and they did scans and showed the carry-over.

Comment: https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/happy-death-day-2017.pdf